# How can I share a variable value between postbacks and without session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, sharepoint

I am creating a custom login page for a sharepoint forms based authentication.

The default page has a login control, and the login control has 2 methods, the signing in and the onauthorize.

The signin gets a userid, whera later I need it to verify the SMS with an external sms provider.

I tried to do this with Session but I get this error

> Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true,
>   either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also
>   make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state
>   module is included in the \\
>   section in the application configuration.

Code

```
namespace Authentication.FBA2FA.CustomLogin.Layouts.Authentication.FBA2FA.CustomLogin
{
    public partial class CustomLoginPage : FormsSignInPage
    {
        private string cellnumber;
        private bool siCell;
        AuthyClient client;
        private string useridAuthy;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        protected void signInControl_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            SecurityToken token = null;
            LoginControl formsLoginControl = sender as LoginControl;

            TextBox txtphone = (TextBox)signInControl.FindControl("tbxPhone");
            TextBox txtSecureCode = (TextBox)signInControl.FindControl("tbxSecureCode");

            client = GetAuthyClient();

    // I need to get the user id here.
            var tokenresult = client.VerifyToken(Session["userid"].ToString(), txtSecureCode.Text);
            if (tokenresult.Status != AuthyStatus.Success)
            {
                siCell = true;
            }
            else
            {
                siCell = false;
            }

            //bSendSms.Click += bSendSms_Click;

            if (null != (token = GetSecurityToken(formsLoginControl)))
            {
                if (siCell)
                {
                    EstablishSessionWithToken(token);
                    e.Authenticated = true;
                    base.RedirectToSuccessUrl(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Authenticated = false;
                }                           
            }
        }
        //private void bSendSms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{            
        //}
        private SPIisSettings IisSettings
        {
            get
            {    
                SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url));
                SPIisSettings settings = webApp.IisSettings[SPUrlZone.Default];
                return settings;
            }
        }

        private SecurityToken GetSecurityToken(LoginControl formsLoginControl)
        {
            SecurityToken token = null;
            SPIisSettings iisSettings = IisSettings;
            Uri appliesTo = base.AppliesTo;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formsLoginControl.UserName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(formsLoginControl.Password))
                return null;

            SPFormsAuthenticationProvider authProvider = iisSettings.FormsClaimsAuthenticationProvider;
            token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(
                appliesTo,
                authProvider.MembershipProvider,
                authProvider.RoleProvider,
                formsLoginControl.UserName,
                formsLoginControl.Password);

            return token;        
        }

        protected void btnSms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txtSecureCode = (TextBox)signInControl.FindControl("tbxSecureCode");
            TextBox txtphone = (TextBox)signInControl.FindControl("tbxPhone");
            int n;
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(txtphone.Text, out n);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtphone.Text) && !isNumeric)
            {
                ClaimsFormsPageMessage.Text = "Please insert a cellphone number";
            }
            else
            {
                cellnumber = txtphone.Text;
                client = GetAuthyClient();
                var result = client.RegisterUser("univer.diego.s@gmail.com", cellnumber, 57);
                useridAuthy = result.UserId;
                // I need to set the user id here.
                Session["userid"] = useridAuthy;

                client.SendSms(result.UserId, true);                
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Because this is Sharepoint, I am not sure if I should do something in the web.config for the web application and if it will do any damage to sharepoint itself.
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying SharePoint's web.config file(s), you can just add `EnableSessionState="True"` to the Page directive on your custom page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableSessionState="True" ... %>
```